# 3 Icheck Control for one event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I have 3 Icheck control, if any of those is Toggled, will call one function event?, is that possible?

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" id="IsZero" name="IsZero" />0
    <span class="pull-right"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" id="IsOne" name="IsOne" />1 
    <span class="pull-right"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class=" i-check" type="checkbox" id="IsTwo" name="IsTwo" />2+
    <span class="pull-right"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

That function event was for sorting:
so if one is checked, then it will display values with one only, eg. if 1 or 2 is checked will display  1's and 2's.

i tried below code:

```
$('input:checkbox.i-check')
$('input.i-check').on('ifToggled'), function(event) {
}
```

but this doesn't trigger them., is there other way?

Comment: sorry, my stupid mistake, this works for me :  $('input:checkbox.i-check').on('ifToggled', function(event) {  });

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this. Instead of `console.log`, you can call your function:

```js
$('input.i-check').on('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        console.log('Checked');
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Unchecked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" id="IsZero" name="IsZero" />0
    <span class="pull-right"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" id="IsOne" name="IsOne" />1 
    <span class="pull-right"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class=" i-check" type="checkbox" id="IsTwo" name="IsTwo" />2+
    <span class="pull-right"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```